# Can I activate abilities in response to spells?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If my opponent plays [Kill! Destroy!](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Kill%21%20Destroy%21) on my [Caldera Kavu](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Caldera%20Kavu), can I activate its ability to turn it black?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes.  You can activate an ability (unless restricted) any time you have priority. Once the spell is on the stack, you place the ability of Caldera Kavu on top. That resolves first, so Kavu is black. Then Kill! Destroy! rechecks the targeting. Since it is invalid, it fizzles and is countered.

> 112.3b Activated abilities have a cost and an effect. They are written as “[Cost]: [Effect.] [Activation instructions (if any).]” A player may activate such an ability whenever he or she has priority.

Comment: By `unless restricted` you mean if someone plays a card that prevents  you from playing an abillity? What (in this case) is a good example?

Comment: @Hurricane996 Some abilities can only be activated, for example, when you could cast a sorcery. So, you get priority a lot during a turn, but you can only use it during your main phases when the stack is empty.